# If statement running both conditions, even though its IMPOSSIBLE to run the second condition if the first is met c#

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

i have some code, for logging in to some software that i'm writing, the code checks the username and password against a file containing the username and hashed passwords, however, if i input any other login than that stored on the first line in the file, both parts of the if statement will run, even though its impossible for 'else' to run if the first condition is met.

I can't seem to find any issues with the code, and of course, if the login details are correct, it logs the user in, even though it gives the error saying that they cannot log in.

code:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("UserData.txt");
string fileLine;
string line;
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) !=null)
{
    fileLine = line;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fileLine);
    string len = fileLine.Length.ToString();
    string usr = fileLine.Substring(0, 20);
    string hash = fileLine.Substring(20, 32);
    if (usr.Contains(UserNameIpt.Text) && hash == password)
    {
        GlobalVar.UserNameEntered = UserNameIpt.Text;
        showUserPanel();
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error, password or username incorrect. \r\n\r\nyou may not have an account set up to use this software, please contact the system administartor for assistance.", "Login Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this code in your debugger? I find it hard to believe that the code executes the `if` and `else` on the same iteration of the `while` loop.

Comment: problem is you would get the error for each line in the file - not for getting to the end so if you had 100 users listed you would get 100 messageboxes.....

Comment: Yes I imagine this is more to do with the while than the if.

Comment: I assume the `if`-branch is hit on the first while the `else`-branch is hit on a later iteration of your while-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain your code to you in pseudo code

lets pretend your file contains only names (to make life shorter) lets say it has

```
jon
kate
alison
fred
bill
```

- So your code says give me a name, i type in pete
- your code then opens the file and reads jon and goes "error"
- reads kate goes "error"
- reads alison goes "error"

  ...

So

You need to change your code slightly

- pick a flag call it say "found" and set it to false
- if I pick kate this time,
- reads jon - does nothing
- reads kate - sets found and breaks
- if found then ok - else say "error"

if I picked pete it would get to the end of the file, found would be false, and it would only once say "error"

Comment: ah, that may well be the case, i'l try that and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

So, i actually managed to solve it, rather than using an isFound condition, i used a nested 'if', replaced 'break' with return, adding it after the error is displayed, and added the error to be displayed after the while statement runs, this seems to be working so far, although its do its probably not the most efficient way to do it.

```
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("UserData.txt");
            string fileLine;
            string line;
            bool isFound = false;
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) !=null)
            {


                fileLine = line;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fileLine);
                string len = fileLine.Length.ToString();
                string usr = fileLine.Substring(0, 20);
                string hash = fileLine.Substring(20, 32);
                if (usr.Contains(UserNameIpt.Text))
                {
                    if (hash == password)
                    {
                        GlobalVar.UserNameEntered = UserNameIpt.Text;
                        showUserPanel();
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error, password or username incorrect. \r\n\r\nyou may not have an account set up to use this software, please contact the system administartor for assistance.", "Login Error");
                        return;
                    }

                }


            }
            MessageBox.Show("Error, password or username incorrect. \r\n\r\nyou may not have an account set up to use this software, please contact the system administartor for assistance.", "Login Error");
```